# Rails 4 - Paperclip does not display uploaded images

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am learning rails, and I am currently following along with Mattan Griffel's 'One Mont Rails.' I have spent a lot of time looking for this answer and have tried everything, but nothing seems to work. I am using the paperclip gem, to upload images, but after upload, the images are not displayed. The only thing displayed, is the missing images icon. Could someone please help. Thank you so much.

Here is a link to my github repo: github.com/robertguss/omrails

Pins Controller: pins_controller.rb

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index]
  before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @pins = Pin.all
    respond_with(@pins)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@pin)
  end

  def new
    @pin = current_user.pins.new
    respond_with(@pin)
  end

  def edit
    @pin = current_user.pins.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @pin = current_user.pins.new(pin_params)
    @pin.save
    respond_with(@pin)
    flash[:success] = "Pin was created successfully!"
  end

  def update
    @pin = current_user.pins.find(params[:id])
    @pin.update(pin_params)
    respond_with(@pin)
    flash[:success] = "Pin was updated successfully!"
  end

  def destroy
    @pin = current_user.pins.find(params[:id])
    @pin.destroy
    respond_with(@pin)
    flash[:alert] = "Pin was deleted!"
  end

  private
    def set_pin
      @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    end

    def pin_params
      params.require(:pin).permit(:description)
    end
end
```

Pins Model = pin.rb

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates :description, presence: true
    has_attached_file :image,
            :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
      :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename"
    validates_attachment :image, content_type: { content_type: ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png' 'image/gif'] },
                                                                size: { less_than: 5.megabytes }

    belongs_to :user

end
```

Answer (score 0):

On your `def pin_params` you should add the permission to image file; so it would be:

```
def pin_params
   params.require(:pin).permit(:description, :image)
end
```